# Reflection can't find private setter on property of abstract class

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

When I have this property in an abstract class:

```
public IList<Component> Components { get; private set; }
```

Then when I call:

```
p.GetSetMethod(true)
```

with p being a PropertyInfo object pointing to my property, I get null.

However if I change the property setter to protected, I can see it via reflection. Why is this? I don't seem to recall having this problem with non-abstract classes...

Comment: I don't understand how this could work for private methods of non-abstract classes.  Can you please provide an SSCCE? http://sscce.org/

Comment: The true parameter to GetSetMethod is supposed to search for non-public members.

Comment: Odd, I'm fairly certain `GetSetMethod(true)` has always resolved private `set` accessors for me, but I don't believe I've used it to resolve members on a base class.  Perhaps there is an inconsistency in the behavior.  Also, are you sure your `PropertyInfo` refers to the correct property, and not a property on a subclass that hides the one you are looking for?

Comment: Nope, don't have any overriding/hiding properties...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume you are calling this on an object from a derived type of your abstract class. There isn't a property setter at all on that class. It is only located on your abstract base. This is why it works when you mark it as `protected`. You need use your abstract class' `Type` instead when getting the property setter.

Comment: Yes, I am calling it from a derived class. That makes sense, that the property setter doesn't exist...

Answer (score 8):

It's an old thread but I run into similar issue recently and none of the above worked for me. Adding my solution as it may be useful for others.

As said before if the setter of a property is private it does not exist in the inherited class. What worked for me was to go one level lower using `DeclaringType` of the `PropertyInfo`

So the code to retrieve the property with the setter would look like this:

```
var propertyInfo = typeof(MyClass)
    .GetProperty("Components", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .DeclaringType
    .GetProperty("Components", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

In this case the `propertyInfo` contains a value for `SetMethod` so you can set the value using reflection.

Comment: Thank you, works great. In my case, I used `someType.GetProperty(name).DeclaringType.GetProperty(name).GetSetMethod(true)` to retrieve the method. This is shorter and works because the property is public, and it's just the setter which is private. I was just missing the `DeclaringType`.

Answer (score 3):

Some brief experimentation in the C# Interactive window suggests that for a property `P` declared on a class `A`, the following works just fine:

```
var p = typeof(A).GetProperty("P").GetSetMethod(true)
```

But as soon as you attempt the same thing with a subclass of `A`, `GetSetMethod` no longer resolves the private `set` accessor:

```
// class B : A {}
var p = typeof(B).GetProperty("P").GetSetMethod(true) // produces 'null'.
```

In other words, what you attempted apparently only works for `private` accessors when the reflected type is the same as the property's declaring type.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use the [BindingFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enumeration to specify that you want private members to be included when you obtain the `PropertyInfo` object:

```
PropertyInfo p = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Components", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work - I still need to set the property setter to protected. Could the fact that I'm using GetProperties to enumerate over all properties have something to do with this?

Comment: @ekolis You have to also use `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy` because your property is in a base class.

Comment: `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy` only applies to static members.

Comment: This doesn't solve his problem.  He can resolve the property; he cannot resolve the `set` accessor.  The problem lies in the type being reflected upon: it needs to be the property's declaring type.

Comment: @MikeStrobel No, it doesn't. It also forces the inclusion of inherited members.

Comment: I tried FlattenHierarchy, and that didn't seem to help... I have in my watch window:

Comment: s.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy).ToArray()[29].GetSetMethod(true) -- which is null (29 being the index of the property in the list of properties which I was looking at in the debugger).

Comment: @TyCobb: Inherited members are included by default; there is no switch to include them, but they can be omitted with `DeclaredOnly`.  `FlattenHierarchy` provides a means of including static members because they are not technically "inherited" (at least according to a somewhat arbitrary definition of 'inherited').

Comment: @MikeStrobel Got it. I will try to remember that next time. I could of sworn I had to use Flatten before with inheritance, but that could have been easily due to it being static and I not realizing it at the time. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

The following experimentation uncovered the issue for me.  Note that the base class doesn't have to be `abstract` to reproduce the problem.

```
public class Base
{
    public string Something { get; private set; }
}

public class Derived : Base { }

public class MiscTest
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var property1 = typeof( Derived ).GetProperty( "Something" );
        var setter1 = property1.SetMethod; //null
        var property2 = typeof( Base ).GetProperty( "Something" );
        var setter2 = property2.SetMethod; //non-null

        bool test1 = property1 == property2; //false
        bool test2 = property1.DeclaringType == property2.DeclaringType; //true

        var solution = property1.DeclaringType.GetProperty( property1.Name );
        var setter3 = solution.SetMethod; //non-null
        bool test3 = solution == property1; //false
        bool test4 = solution == property2; //true
        bool test5 = setter3 == setter2; //true
    }
}
```

What I learned from this and found surprising, is that the `PropertyInfo` on the derived type is a different instance than the `PropertyInfo` on the base type.  Weird!

Answer (score 0):

To build on the work of @piotrwolkowski

```
var flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
var propertyInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("Components", flags);

// only go to the declaring type if you need to
if (!propertyInfo.CanWrite)
    propertyInfo = propertyInfo.DeclaringType.GetProperty("Components", flags);
```

I added both public and non-public to the binding flags for my use case (it may be overkill and I don't have the time to pursue it further)

I was setting the instance of an object that inherited from an abstract base with public get and private set

Again, all credit to @piotrwolkowski