# Will PropertyInfo from Expression be equal to PropertyInfo from GetProperties()

Tags: c#, reflection, types, lambda

I know that `typeof(T) == typeof(T)` will always be true because `Type` objects are basically static and only one `Type` instance exists per class type (if this is wrong, please correct me...I have several programs that function on this assumption).

I am having a hard time finding in the documentation whether or not the `PropertyInfo` objects exhibit the same property.

My application is this:

I have a `Reflector<T>` class which takes the result `typeof(T).GetProperties(...)` and stores the resulting `PropertyInfo` objects as keys in a dictionary.

Separately, I have an expression parser which attempts to parse an expression describing the access of a certain property of type `Func<T, TResult>` (e.g. `t => t.SomeProperty` with `T` being `t.GetType()` and `TResult` being the type of `SomeProperty`). After some computation, I eventually get a `PropertyInfo` object coming from a `MemberExpression.Member` from the passed `Expression`.

The resulting `PropertyInfo` is then used as the key in a `Dictionary.TryGetValue` call to get the additional data about the property stored in the `Reflector<T>`'s dictionary.

**Question**

Can I be assured that the `PropertyInfo` that comes from the `MemberExpression.Member` will be equal to (`==`) the `PropertyInfo` for the same property returned from `Type.GetProperties` or could there be two different `PropertyInfo` instances that in actuality refer to the same property on the same type?

For the purpose of discussion, it may be assumed that the property is non-virtual or not overridden if it is virtual.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [reference source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Ast/MemberExpression.cs), it should be. The PropertyInfo instance is being obtained from the matching Type.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of whether or not the property is `virtual` or overridden, the `PropertyInfo` on a derived type is always different than the one on the base type where it's defined.

When working with the `MemberExpression.Member` from a lambda of the form `() => someInstance.SomeProperty`, you may retrieve a `PropertyInfo` from a derived type.  As I uncovered in my [answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46656353), it's different instance than the `PropertyInfo` you get from the base type itself.